# Python split one column into multiple columns and reattach the split columns into original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split one column from my dataframe into multiple columns, then attach those columns back to my original dataframe and divide my original dataframe based on whether the split columns include a specific string.

I have a dataframe that has a column with values separated by semicolons like below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ID':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'], 
    'Residence':['USA;CA;Los Angeles;Los Angeles', 'USA;MA;Suffolk;Boston', 'Canada;ON','USA;FL;Charlotte', 'NA', 'Canada;QC', 'USA;AZ'],
    'Name':['Ann','Betty','Carl','David','Emily','Frank', 'George'],
    'Gender':['F','F','M','M','F','M','M']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I split the column as below, and separated the split column into two based on whether it contains the string `USA` or not.

```
address = df['Residence'].str.split(';',expand=True)
country = address[0] != 'USA'
USA, nonUSA = address[~country], address[country]
```

Now if you run `USA` and `nonUSA`, you'll note that there are extra columns in `nonUSA`, and also a row with no country information. So I got rid of those `NA` values.

```
USA.columns = ['Country', 'State', 'County', 'City']
nonUSA.columns = ['Country', 'State']
nonUSA = nonUSA.dropna(axis=0, subset=[1])
nonUSA = nonUSA[nonUSA.columns[0:2]]
```

Now I want to attach `USA` and `nonUSA` to my original dataframe, so that I will get two dataframes that look like below:

```
USAdata = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','4','7'], 
    'Name':['Ann','Betty','David','George'],
    'Gender':['F','F','M','M'],
    'Country':['USA','USA','USA','USA'],
    'State':['CA','MA','FL','AZ'],
    'County':['Los Angeles','Suffolk','Charlotte','None'],
    'City':['Los Angeles','Boston','None','None']})
nonUSAdata = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['3','6'], 
    'Name':['David','Frank'],
    'Gender':['M','M'],
    'Country':['Canada', 'Canada'],
    'State':['ON','QC']})
```

I'm stuck here though. How can I split my original dataframe into people whose `Residence` include `USA` or not, and attach the split columns from `Residence` ( `USA` and `nonUSA` ) back to my original dataframe?

(Also, I just uploaded everything I had so far, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner/smarter way to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unique index in original data and is not changed in next code for both DataFrames, so you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join together and then add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or `concat` with `axis=1`:

```
address = df['Residence'].str.split(';',expand=True)
country = address[0] != 'USA'
USA, nonUSA = address[~country], address[country]
USA.columns = ['Country', 'State', 'County', 'City']

nonUSA = nonUSA.dropna(axis=0, subset=[1])
nonUSA = nonUSA[nonUSA.columns[0:2]]
#changed order for avoid error
nonUSA.columns = ['Country', 'State']
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.concat([USA, nonUSA])], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = df.join(pd.concat([USA, nonUSA]))
print (df)
  ID                       Residence    Name Gender Country State  \
0  1  USA;CA;Los Angeles;Los Angeles     Ann      F     USA    CA   
1  2           USA;MA;Suffolk;Boston   Betty      F     USA    MA   
2  3                       Canada;ON    Carl      M  Canada    ON   
3  4                USA;FL;Charlotte   David      M     USA    FL   
4  5                              NA   Emily      F     NaN   NaN   
5  6                       Canada;QC   Frank      M  Canada    QC   
6  7                          USA;AZ  George      M     USA    AZ   

        County         City  
0  Los Angeles  Los Angeles  
1      Suffolk       Boston  
2          NaN          NaN  
3    Charlotte         None  
4          NaN          NaN  
5          NaN          NaN  
6         None         None
```

But it seems it is possible simplify:

```
c = ['Country', 'State', 'County', 'City']
df[c] = df['Residence'].str.split(';',expand=True)
print (df)
  ID                       Residence    Name Gender Country State  \
0  1  USA;CA;Los Angeles;Los Angeles     Ann      F     USA    CA   
1  2           USA;MA;Suffolk;Boston   Betty      F     USA    MA   
2  3                       Canada;ON    Carl      M  Canada    ON   
3  4                USA;FL;Charlotte   David      M     USA    FL   
4  5                              NA   Emily      F      NA  None   
5  6                       Canada;QC   Frank      M  Canada    QC   
6  7                          USA;AZ  George      M     USA    AZ   

        County         City  
0  Los Angeles  Los Angeles  
1      Suffolk       Boston  
2         None         None  
3    Charlotte         None  
4         None         None  
5         None         None  
6         None         None
```

Comment: Your first way works perfectly, I had no idea I could just concatenate the dataframes together. For the simplified version, I'm wondering if it's possible to do something similar to it if my column names for `USA` and `nonUSA` were not overlapping. (For instance, if `USA` column names were still `['Country', 'State', 'County', 'City'] but if `nonUSA` column names were `['CountryB', 'StateB']` or something like that, would a similar approach still work?

Comment: @Jen - If need different columns names need your solution, then get missing values for `['CountryB', 'StateB']` for `USA` rows, and missing values in `['Country', 'State', 'County', 'City']` for `nonUSA` rows.